# Full width navigation with flexbox and space-between

Tags: css

I'm using flexbox for a full width navigation and space-between to distribute the navigation items.

I need the nav hyperlinks to take up all the space between each nav item but when I set each LI to flex: 1 it breaks the space-between and the items are not distributed evenly anymore.

```css
.site-header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-header-nav li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.site-header-nav a {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-header-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Design Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Marketing Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hosting Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Search Marketing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added

```css
    .site-header-nav li {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1;
          justify-content: center;
        }
```

and for each `a`

```css
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
```

to distribute them as you want

```css
.site-header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-header-nav li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.site-header-nav a {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-header-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Design Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Marketing Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hosting Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Search Marketing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't set a fixed width to the list items. First of all, I have eight so I would have to lower 25% to 12.5%, second, that's not enough width to hold the item text.

Comment: Then you can manage it again with flexbox if you do not want to give width, I updated my answer @Junky

Comment: I updated my code sample to actual menu items. You can see that the items still do not align properly.

Comment: Because you are not using my css solution, I still see different css in your code. Look I put your html in my code and it align properly @Junky

Comment: Unfortunately when you add flex: 1 to .site-header-nav li you lose justify-content: space-between on .site-header-nav and the menu is no longer edge to edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `width: -webkit-fill-available;` on your `.site-header-nav-2`. This works simultaneously with setting `width: inherit;` on `.site-header-nav-2 a` and your `.site-header-nav-2 li`. This will ensure that all your nav hyperlinks will take up all the space between each nav item. I added a gap just to demonstrate the inherited with. See the changes below.

Also, you forgot to close your `<li>`'s

```css
.site-header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-header-nav li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.site-header-nav a {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.site-header-nav-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    gap: 10px;
}
.site-header-nav-2 li {
  width: inherit;
}

.site-header-nav-2 a {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>Hyperlink is full width of LI but not space-between</p>
<ul class="site-header-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Hyperlink is not full width of LI but is space-between</p>
<ul class="site-header-nav-2">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

```css
.site-header-nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-header-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


.site-header-nav a {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  li a {
    font-size: smaller;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div class="site-header-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Design Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Marketing Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hosting Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search Marketing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I updated my code sample to actual menu items. You can see that the items still do not align properly.

Comment: @Junky Honestly, I thought your question was about sub-menu links aligning properly under their parent, which is what my first bit covers. I added another snippet with your updated post, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this. When I view your code snippet at full screen, you can see the problem. I'm trying to get each hyperlink (yellow background) to stretch to the next hyperlink so that there's no blank spaces without losing the justification and without knowing the length of each item.

Comment: @Junky so you're saying you want each `ul` to take 100% of flex space while maintaining the navbar of 100% width? So essentially the items are spaced out the same as the snippet, but the ul's yellow background extends to from one `li` to another?

Comment: Yes but more specifically the li and the  <a> to extend the full width of each li so there's no dead space between each li <a>.

Comment: I'll have to retry when I get back to the offce. I'll update then.